# Android audio player ui

Tags: android

this is my layout for audio player the problem is when resolution is high there is balck space vacant under the play and delete button which  located at the bottom of the ui. what i do?

```
>
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="840dp"
android:background="#333134"
    >
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
    <TextView 
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/Rec_Timer_ID"
    android:text="00:00" 
    android:textSize="70sp"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout 
                                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                                                        <Button 
                                                            android:id ="@+id/Button_record_sound"
                                                            android:background="@drawable/rec_btn"
                                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

                                                            />  
                            </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                >

                                <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                                >






                                 <LinearLayout  android:layout_height="20dp"
                                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                                 <View
                                    android:id="@+id/View1"
                                    android:background= "#ffffff"
                                    android:layout_width="5dp"
                                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                                        />
                                 </LinearLayout>    


                                            <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/Description"
                                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                        android:textStyle="bold"
                                        android:textSize="13sp"
                                        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                                        android:gravity="top"
                                        android:minLines="2"
                                        android:maxLines="2"
                                        />  


                    </LinearLayout>  


                      <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                                >

                                 <LinearLayout  android:layout_height="20dp"
                                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                                 <View
                                    android:id="@+id/View22"
                                    android:background= "#ffffff"
                                    android:layout_width="5dp"
                                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                                        />
                                 </LinearLayout>    


                        <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Description2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:minLines="2"
                    android:maxLines="2"

                    />  
                    </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
<ImageView
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/bar1"/>

<LinearLayout
                                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                 android:clickable="false"
                                 android:orientation="horizontal">      
                                                              <TextView
                                                              android:id="@+id/TimerStart"
                                                              android:text="00:00"
                                                              android:textSize="11sp"
                                                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>                                  
                                                              <SeekBar

                                                              android:padding="7dp"
                                                              android:id="@+id/SeekBar01" 
                                                              android:layout_width="245dip" 

                                                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                              android:clickable="false"
                                                              android:focusable="false"
                                                              android:longClickable="false"

                                                              />
                                                               <TextView
                                                              android:id="@+id/TimerStop"
                                                              android:text="00:00"
                                                              android:textSize="11sp"
                                                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 

                             </LinearLayout>    



 <LinearLayout


                                        android:background="@drawable/br_12"
                                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"

                                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                                        >   





                                                        <Button 
                                                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                                            android:id ="@+id/Button_Play_Sound"
                                                            android:background="@drawable/play1"
                                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 


                                                            />  

                                                           <Button 
                                                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                                            android:visibility="invisible"
                                                            android:layout_width="8dp"
                                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 


                                                            />  
                                                            <Button 
                                                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"

                                                            android:id ="@+id/Button_Delete_Sound"
                                                            android:background="@drawable/trash"
                                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 



                                                            />


                 </LinearLayout>
                 </LinearLayout>

                 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not done much android programming but have you thought about creating multiple UI's for different screen resolutions?

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: for large medium and small i have created ui, and tested with two phone is it ok now but i have a doubt that all small have same resolution ...